# Get rows from table1 missing in table2 oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables as below. am using Oracle 10g

```
TableA
---------
id  Name
--- ----
1   abc
2   def
3   xxx
4   yyy

TableB
---------
id  Name
--- ----
1   abc
2   def

TableC
---------
id  Name
--- ----
1   abc
2   def
```

Now i need to get the ids `from TableA which are not there in TableB and TableC`. How can i do this without using NOT IN clause?

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: wt if you join the two tables with id not equals condition and get the distinct ids ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
  a.ID, 
  a.NAME
FROM 
  TABLEA a LEFT JOIN TABLEB b ON a.ID=b.ID 
    LEFT JOIN TABLEC c ON a.ID=c.ID
WHERE 
  b.ID IS NULL AND 
  c.ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from TableA
minus
select * from TableB
```

---

**EDIT :**

that are not in B and C simultaneously:

```
select * from TableA
minus (
  select * from TableB
  intersect
  select * from TableC
)
```

that are not in B or in C:

```
select * from TableA
minus 
select * from TableB
minus
select * from TableC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id
from tableA a,tableB b,tableC c
where a.id != b.id and a.id!=c.id
```

is this fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from TableA
minus
(select * from TableB
union
select * from TableC)
```